# JAX-WS dynamic webservice url

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws, jboss6.x

Here's my requirement for a university class: I have to develop a web service that different hotels must implement. For instance they all have to implement the method `boolean checkAvailability(Room r, Date from, Date to)`. So I store their web service's URL and call that method whenever I want to know wether they have certain room available.

I have to use SOAP in this case, and because each hotel has a different DNS name, etc I need to set the url for the endpoint dynamically (retrieve it from the database and then use it). I have not found an easy tutorial on how to do this.

I'm running on Jboss AS 6, using JAX-WS specification, JAVA EE 6.

I need help desperatly (Please do not edit that, I really am desperate).